# get_post_meta isn't returning anything in shortcode

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, shortcode

I'm trying to add a set of testimonials (custom post-type) to my page via a shortcode. The short code (shown below) outputs on the page and it is pulling 4 entries from the 4 testimonials created ... but get_post_meta isn't returning anything. Not sure if there is something I don't know about working with post data via short codes. Any thoughts?

Site is up at penderair.yourbrandstronger.com

```
<?php

/* Testimonial shortcode */

if (!function_exists('ybs_testimonials')) {
function ybs_testimonials() {

$html = '<ul class="testimonials">';

    $testimonials_arguments = array(
                                    'post_type' => 'testimonial',
                                    'posts_per_page' => 5
                                   );

    $testimonials_query = new WP_Query( $testimonials_arguments );

    if ( $testimonials_query->have_posts() ) 
    {                                                                                               
        while ( $testimonials_query->have_posts() ) :                                               
        $testimonials_query->the_post();
        $testimonial_content = get_post_meta($post->ID,'the_testimonial', true);
        $testimonial_author = get_post_meta($post->ID,'testimonial_author', true);                                                      
            $html .= '<li>';

                if ( has_post_thumbnail() )
                {       
                    $html .= '<div class="imgbox">' . the_post_thumbnail('testimonial-thumb') . '</div>';                           
                }

                $html .= '<div class="detail">
                        <blockquote>
                                <p>' . $testimonial_content . '</p>
                        </blockquote>
                        <p class="author">' . $testimonial_author . '</p>
                </div>                                                                                                             
            </li>';                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        endwhile;                                                           
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    $html .= '</ul>';

return $html;
}
}
add_shortcode('ybs_testimonials', 'ybs_testimonials');
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, problem solved. Just needed to change: $post->ID to get_the_ID() in my get_post_meta calls.